# `require.resolve()` still detecting module after an uninstall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

This was meant to be a 2 hour task, turned into this monstrosity.

So now, I've tried installing node-fetch using this, and it seems to have worked once, but I changed something to make it more appealing, then used `npm uninstall node-fetch` and it no longer wants to install... Maybe `require.resolve()` is just a one-time use?

Specifically this line is mad: `return require.main.require(moduleWanted);`

Not quite sure what might have caused this, also any suggested general code-improvements are highly appreciated.

```js
RigidDeps.NPMInstaller = function(moduleWanted) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let cp = require("child_process")
      try {
          require.resolve(moduleWanted); // Check if the module exists
      } catch (e) { // It Doesn't
          console.log(`Rigid Dependencies || Module not found -> "${moduleWanted}"...\nAttempting to Install...`); // Tell the user it's installing
          cp.execSync(`npm install --prefix "${__dirname}" ${moduleWanted}`); // Do the NPM command.
          console.log(`Rigid Dependencies || "${moduleWanted}" has been installed.`);
      }

      // The Install attempt has been made, continue...
      console.log("attempted")

      try {
          resolve("Done.")
          return require.main.require(moduleWanted);
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
          console.log(`Rigid Dependencies || Failed to Install "${moduleWanted}". Run from CMD or Install Manually: "npm i --save ${moduleWanted}".`);
          process.exit(1);
      }
  });
};

RigidDeps.require = async function(moduleReq) {
  this.NPMInstaller(moduleReq).then(function(result) { // Runs the Auto-Installer
    console.log("I got this far.")

    let botPath;
    let modulePath;

        try {
          botPath = path.dirname(process.argv[1]);
          modulePath = path.join(botPath, "node_modules", moduleReq);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
    console.log("Did this");

  try {
    return require.main.require(modulePath);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  }, function(error) { // Gets Auto-Installer Errors
    console.log(error);
    return;
  })
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: Tried for other modules, it actually doesn't work at all, require.resolve() does its thing, but the installer doesn't.